# Realizar accion al detectar una imagen en pantalla

Tags: imagen

Existe alguna forma (en algun lenguaje) en el cual se pueda detectar una imagen en pantalla y al detectarla realizar una accion?
teniendo una imagen del objeto o cosa que se quiere detectar (guardandola previamente), para que este pueda compararlo.

un ejemplo facil para expresarme: un juego

en pantalla tiene distintos menus y objetos, la idea es poder detectar esa "x" cosa y hacer click en "y" cosa, obviamente teniendo la opcion de poder crear condiciones (como por ejemplo, si en pantalla esta el objeto "J" y el objeto "P" no se realiza la accion, de lo contrario si), pero todo basado en lo que hay en pantalla.

Desconozco completamente si es posible, busque pero no encontre nada parecido.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es emplear la librería `pyautogui` de Python (seguramente encuentres librerías equivalentes en otros lenguajes).

Esta solución puede valerte o no dependiendo de las características del programa que desarrolles: si necesitas mucha velocidad y cómo de fácilmente reconocibles sean los objetos (si cambia el fondo sobre el que se encuentra, etc.). Además de que los objetos siempre tienen que estar en la misma posición y tamaño.

```
import pyautogui

PIC_J = 'img\\j.bmp' # Ruta de imagen del objeto J
PIC_P = 'img\\p.bmp' # Ruta de imagen del objeto P

object_j = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(PIC_J)
object_p = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(PIC_P)

if not (object_j and object_p):
    # Accion a realizar cuando uno o los dos objetos no esta
    ...
```

La función `locateOnScreen` puede tomar el parámetro `confidence` que te permite establecer un umbral de precisión a la hora de reconocer el objeto (necesitas instalar OpenCV). Si el objeto no se encuentra, devolverá `None` y si se localiza devolverá un objeto `Box` con las coordenadas y las dimensiones.

Puedes encontrar más funciones [aquí](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Por el contrario, si no encaja con las necesidades de tu proyecto, quizá debas recurrir a librerías de visión computacional como OpenCV o SimpleCV o algoritmos de inteligencia artificial.